# can't install phpmyadmin have error

Tags: centos, lamp, centos7

I have some error when I tried to install phpmyadin, did I miss something?

CentOS 7

```
# wget http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/e/epel-release-7-2.noarch.rpm

# wget http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-7.rpm

# rpm -Uvh remi-release-7*.rpm epel-release-7*.rpm

# yum update

# yum --enablerepo=remi,remi-php55 install php php-common

# yum --enablerepo=remi,remi-php55 install php-gd php-pdo php-mysql

# yum install mysql

# yum install mariadb-server

# systemctl start mariadb

# mysql_secure_installation

# service httpd start

#  yum install phpmyadmin or  yum --enablerepo=remi install phpmyadmin
```

error

```
Error: Package: php-mbstring-5.4.34-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.34-1.el7.remi
           Installed: php-common-5.5.18-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (@remi-php55)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.5.18-1.el7.remi
           Available: php-common-5.4.16-21.el7.x86_64 (base)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.16-21.el7
           Available: php-common-5.4.16-23.el7_0.x86_64 (updates)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.16-23.el7_0
           Available: php-common-5.4.16-23.el7_0.1.x86_64 (updates)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.16-23.el7_0.1
           Available: php-common-5.4.16-23.el7_0.3.x86_64 (updates)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.16-23.el7_0.3
           Available: php-common-5.4.33-2.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.33-2.el7.remi
           Available: php-common-5.4.34-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.34-1.el7.remi
Error: Package: php-recode-5.4.34-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.34-1.el7.remi
           Installed: php-common-5.5.18-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (@remi-php55)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.5.18-1.el7.remi
           Available: php-common-5.4.16-21.el7.x86_64 (base)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.16-21.el7
           Available: php-common-5.4.16-23.el7_0.x86_64 (updates)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.16-23.el7_0
           Available: php-common-5.4.16-23.el7_0.1.x86_64 (updates)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.16-23.el7_0.1
           Available: php-common-5.4.16-23.el7_0.3.x86_64 (updates)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.16-23.el7_0.3
           Available: php-common-5.4.33-2.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.33-2.el7.remi
           Available: php-common-5.4.34-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.34-1.el7.remi
Error: Package: php-tidy-5.4.34-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.34-1.el7.remi
           Installed: php-common-5.5.18-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (@remi-php55)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.5.18-1.el7.remi
           Available: php-common-5.4.16-21.el7.x86_64 (base)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.16-21.el7
           Available: php-common-5.4.16-23.el7_0.x86_64 (updates)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.16-23.el7_0
           Available: php-common-5.4.16-23.el7_0.1.x86_64 (updates)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.16-23.el7_0.1
           Available: php-common-5.4.16-23.el7_0.3.x86_64 (updates)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.16-23.el7_0.3
           Available: php-common-5.4.33-2.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.33-2.el7.remi
           Available: php-common-5.4.34-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.34-1.el7.remi
Error: Package: php-mcrypt-5.4.34-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.34-1.el7.remi
           Installed: php-common-5.5.18-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (@remi-php55)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.5.18-1.el7.remi
           Available: php-common-5.4.16-21.el7.x86_64 (base)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.16-21.el7
           Available: php-common-5.4.16-23.el7_0.x86_64 (updates)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.16-23.el7_0
           Available: php-common-5.4.16-23.el7_0.1.x86_64 (updates)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.16-23.el7_0.1
           Available: php-common-5.4.16-23.el7_0.3.x86_64 (updates)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.16-23.el7_0.3
           Available: php-common-5.4.33-2.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.33-2.el7.remi
           Available: php-common-5.4.34-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.34-1.el7.remi
Error: Package: php-bcmath-5.4.34-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.34-1.el7.remi
           Installed: php-common-5.5.18-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (@remi-php55)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.5.18-1.el7.remi
           Available: php-common-5.4.16-21.el7.x86_64 (base)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.16-21.el7
           Available: php-common-5.4.16-23.el7_0.x86_64 (updates)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.16-23.el7_0
           Available: php-common-5.4.16-23.el7_0.1.x86_64 (updates)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.16-23.el7_0.1
           Available: php-common-5.4.16-23.el7_0.3.x86_64 (updates)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.16-23.el7_0.3
           Available: php-common-5.4.33-2.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.33-2.el7.remi
           Available: php-common-5.4.34-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.34-1.el7.remi
```

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clue is in the error message:

```
Error: Package: php-mbstring-5.4.34-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi)
       Requires: php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.34-1.el7.remi
       Installed: php-common-5.5.18-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (@remi-php55)
           php-common(x86-64) = 5.5.18-1.el7.remi

Error: Package: php-recode-5.4.34-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi)
       Requires: php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.34-1.el7.remi
       Installed: php-common-5.5.18-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (@remi-php55)
```

You're running php55 from the remi repo, but phpmyadmin relies on php54 components. I am not sure of the best way to go forward but you have a few options to look in to. Either you can try installing the php55 versions of php-mbstring and php-recode. But at a guess you will probably get the same errors as it **NEEDS** that version of the dependencies.

You could try using php 5.4 instead of php 5.5, if you don't need php 5.5 for any particular reason it is probably best to go with this anyway as it is likely to be more stable than php 5.5.

If you **NEED** php 5.5 have a look to see if there is a newer version of phpmyadmin that supports php5.5, it might not be available in the repositories though, you might have to build from source. Sorry I don't have all the answers, I just saw what looked like an obvious issue and thought I would point it out. You could do:

```
yum provides phpmyadmin
```

This should show you what options you have from the repos you have installed, you might need to add the enable repo command if you haven't set them to enabled in the /etc/yum.repo.d/ conf files (assuming they haven't moved in CentOS 7 - I haven't tried it yet).

I hope that helps!

Comment: thanks for reply! I use yum provides phpmyadmin and it shows phpMyAdmin-4.2.10-1.el7.noarch : Handle the administration of MySQL over the
                               : World Wide Web
Repo        : epel
Matched from:
Provides    : phpmyadmin = 4.2.10-1.el7

Comment: and i tried `yum --enablerepo=epel install phpmyadmin` still not work

Comment: If that is the only version of phpmyadmin then you probably need to look at downgrading php to php5.4 and then try it again. Currently you are trying to install phpmyadmin to run with php5.5 when it relies on php5.4. Alternatively you might look at compiling phpmyadmin from source - but I wouldn't recommend it. This is a normal issue when using the newest versions of software on CentOS. CentOS tends to use slightly older versions as they can be more stable

Comment: I install `# yum --enablerepo=remi,remi-php55 install php-tidy php-bcmath php-mcrypt php-mbstring` and  `# yum install phpMyAdmin.noarch`  it work, is there any problem if I do this ??

Comment: I'm not sure whether the version of phpmyadmin will work with that version of php I am afraid, you should prbably check the documentation. But I would expect you should find out quite quickly if they are incompatible. Try logging in, see if you get any errors...

Comment: yes, I can log in, so do you still use cents 6.5??  and if I try to use php 5.5 are you recommend use  repo like remi ?

Comment: I am using CentOS 5 on some servers that rely on old kernels (not by choice) my own media server runs CentOS 6.6, but I haven't had a need to try CentOS 7 yet. Normally I find it's a good idea to let a new version have at least 6 months before considering using it for production. You're likely to find bugs when you're an early adopter. If you want to use remi, epel, rpmforge etc that's up to you, a lot of people advise against it, and generally it's for stability reasons they recommend you don't use them in production. I personally have never encountered major issues, but I'm sure some have